button is pressed when starting scrolling in iOS 18
On iOS 18, while on a modal screen, if the scrolling starts on a button, that button gets pressed, outside of a modal this doesn't reproduce, also not reproducible on older iOS versions, neither on modals or outside of them.
The code to reproduce the issue:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var presentModal = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            presentModal = true
        }, label: {
            Text("open modal")
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $presentModal, content: {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(0..<100, id: \.self) { index in
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Button \(index) tapped!")
                    }) {
                        Text("Button \(index)")
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .frame(height: 100)
                            .background(randomColor(for: index))
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
    
    func randomColor(for index: Int) -> Color {
        let hue = Double(index % 100) / 100.0
        return Color(hue: hue, saturation: 0.8, brightness: 0.8)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}



A workaround is to use .onTapGesture, instead of a Button.
